# How do I take off body armor in GTA V online?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-online

I am sick of the Armor, and I want to wear a purple shirt. In my attempts to remove the armor I have used the select option, gone into stores, and went into my wardrobe. How do I take the armor off?

Comment: no I have read the others and none have helped, I have tried everything I have read !

Answer (score 1):

Depends whether you are playing on Xbox or Playstation...

For xbox:

1. Click the 'back' button.
2. Go to Inventory..
3. Go to body Armour and set it to none.

same applies to PlayStation except back = select

Comment: I have done that repeatedly no result

Comment: thank you I figured it out it never said to press square

Comment: np! ...tbh I wrote this answer from memory... I haven't played GTA V in a little while ;)

Comment: ya legit nobody has ever said press square so frustrated lol